# Changing Dataframe Elements After Filtering With .loc

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter the 7 columns below, and then with all results I would like to change the 'Impressions' column to 1000.

When I run this, I get a single large column of boolean results. What am I doing wrong?

The original dataset is located here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DGH-qOMqysxZqa-kcV22H6huXwUduOQj/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102686771640548691831&rtpof=true&sd=true

```
df.loc[
    (((df['Record Type'].str.lower() == 'keyword')
    | (df['Record Type'].str.lower() == 'product targeting')) &
    ((df['Campaign Status'].str.lower() == 'enabled')
    & (df['Ad Group Status'].str.lower() == 'enabled')
    & (df['Status'].str.lower() == 'enabled'))
    & df['Orders'] > 0
    & df['Campaign'].str.contains('b0',case=False))
    ,"Impressions"] > 1000
```

Comment: Always provide a minimal reproducible example when asking for help. Kindly post a sample of the DataFrame that allows us to reproduce the same output.

Comment: My appoligies - I have added a link to the dataset that I am using with this. Is this adequate?  thank you

Comment: I can't open it, it requires permission.  You don't need to provide the whole data. We just need the minimal amount of data that allows us to reproduce the same behaviour. You should post it directly inside a code block.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do this with [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
condition = (
             ((df['Record Type'].str.lower() == 'keyword') | (df['Record Type'].str.lower() == 'product targeting')) &
             ((df['Campaign Status'].str.lower() == 'enabled') & (df['Ad Group Status'].str.lower() == 'enabled') & (df['Status'].str.lower() == 'enabled')) & 
             df['Orders'] > 0 & 
             df['Campaign'].str.contains('b0',case=False)
             )

df["Impression"] = df["Impression"].where(~condition, 1000)
```

Or with [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html#pandas.DataFrame.mask):

```
df["Impression"] = df["Impression"].mask(condition, 1000)
```